# Sending bwav metadata/description to an external colleague

Tags: metadata, soundminer

Hello to this amazing stack.

This is potentially quite a simple question but
my friend who knows soundminer inside-out is on holiday.

We'v just had a heap (200gb+) of wildtracks come in for a film
and I am writing descriptions for them using soundminer 3.2

My colleague has a copy of the same files, but works from home.

To save posting him a drive, **Does anyone know if it's possible to just send the metadata (description field) and not the files?**

Or perhaps someone has found a better solution for this issue.

also, incase anyone missed it check out Udo Noll's - www.aporee.org/maps/

cheers all.

LoL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export .txt

On his/her side, s/he can import text

Comment: Okay Thanks. 

Just to clarify a little.

If i get him to make a database and add the same files.

He can just import my exported txt.

( im going to just do this and then report back, to save you answering)

THANKS!

Comment: I ended up working out a different sorting method so i havent tried this yet, cheers anyway Mr.Kai